# How to find the mean of a filtered table

Tags: r, rstudio

I am new to R, but I am having trouble with getting the results I want. 
I have a huge table with various columns, and one of the is boolean, lets call it HaveSalad, where 1 = has salad in the menu, and 0 = doesnt have salad in the menu.
In another column, I have numeric values, lets call it Rating, which shows the number I rated this restaurant

I am looking to find a the mean value of Rating when I filter my data to show only restaurants where HaveSalad = 1.

When I try to apply the filter directly to the table using the Filter button on the toolbar, all I get is the same mean as I get without applying the filter. I am completely stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `==` to create a logical vector and get the corresponding values of 'Rating' and get the `mean`

```
with(df1, mean(Rating[HaveSalad == 1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or with `as.logical`

```
with(df1, mean(Rating[as.logical(HaveSalad)], na.rm = TRUE))
```